# How to run FFMPEG commands from android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am new with ffmpeg, so what I want is to run the ffmpeg commands through my native C file.I had seen some example which said to pass the command in the `main()` function of `ffmpeg.c` file. I am doing the same but I am getting `undefined reference to 'main'`. How can we run basic ffmpeg commands in android?